# Conversion failed when converting the varchar to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this query, I need to save Pubname, ISBNname, copiesname and createdname as Integers

```
DECLARE @a Table(bkID INT, bkname varchar(100), bkpub INT, bkISBN INT, bkcopies INT, bkcreatedby INT)
        INSERT INTO @a (bkID, bkname, bkpub, bkISBN, bkcopies, bkcreatedby)
        SELECT A.nameID,
        A.bkname,           
        CAST((B.Pubname) AS INT),
        CAST((C.ISBNname) AS int),
        CAST((D.copiesname) AS int),
        CAST((F.createdname) AS int)
        FROM @bkname AS A
        LEFT JOIN @bkPub AS B
        ON (A.nameID = PubID)
        LEFT JOIN @bkISBN AS C
        ON (A.nameID = C.ISBNID)
        LEFT JOIN @bkcopies AS D
        ON (A.nameID = D.copiesID)
        LEFT JOIN @bkcraeted AS F
        ON (A.nameID = F.craetedID)
```

---

It returns this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LR_InsertBookArray, Line 46
>   [Batch Start Line 2] Conversion failed when converting the varchar
>   value ''3' to data type int.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Your error message says ''3'.  There is an extra quote there, looks like you are inserting '3

Comment: Can you run the SELECT stand-alone?

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @PugFugly Updated.

Comment: @jarlh yes work and give true results when execute in Query alone; but in stored procedure No!

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: Please include just enough code so we can re-create: a (simpler) table definition, what is `@bkname`, etc.

Comment: oooh,, the problem is I need to call another 2 procedure to execute it

Comment: I test it and I can tell you the problem is system doesn't convert varchar to int datatype,, and I am sure my data is numbers

Comment: You sure you don't have quotes in your value ?  ---- Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''3' to data type int. Because, the exception says ''3'

Comment: TRY_CAST fix the problem.. Thank you

Comment: You need names as integers? Why? TRY_CAST "fixes" the problem, as in it no longer returns an error, but any string that can't be cast to an integer just becomes NULL. I'm not sure I would classify that as fixed.

Comment: its not names.. just instead write description to take the value I write names.. the data is integers :)

Comment: I am try to enter the data as integer because I call procedure read data as varchar to put it as rows in one column instead array... the data entered like this 'goo,soo,doo,foo' and '1,2,3,4' so I need to made it as rows in column then add it with another procedure!..I am still get null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems highly unlikely that columns called `name` are actually integers in disguise.  My guess is that you simply want the ids from the reference table, but your question doesn't have enough information to know if that is true.

In the meantime, you can use `TRY_CAST()`:

```
    TRY_CAST(B.Pubname AS int),
    TRY_CAST(C.ISBNname AS int),
    TRY_CAST(D.copiesname AS int),
    TRY_CAST(F.createdname AS int)
```

This will return `NULL` if the values cannot be converted -- but it avoids the error.

Comment: 1 Million Thank You

Comment: yes it give me null values,, btw my data is integers